# Combining multiple queries in solr?

Tags: solr

I have multiple content source over which i am querying and getting search results. If i query them in isolation, everything is working fine.

Getting one set of results using "Raw Query Parameters"

```
http://solrserver/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true&_query_=%22AuthenticatedUserName=lalit%22
```

Getting another set of results using filter query fq

```
http://solrserver/solr/collection1/select?q=*%3A*&fq=alf_acls%3AGROUP_EVERYONE&wt=json&indent=true
```

But i am not able to combine these two queries into one query and get all results. If i try with fq first, first set of results is not updated and i get second set of results only. If i use "Raw Query Parameters" first then, second set is not available. I can not put "Raw Query Parameters" as fq parameters as these present are not in schema.

Is there any way to get all results simultaneously with all different queries combined as i tries sub-queries but it did not work? Or is there any way to combine results of multiple queries into one set and render it?

Finally both sets of documents are stored in same core but are not related to each other.

Can anybody help?